# Using Google Apps Script as service to retrieve data from spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I'm new to this technique and have been researching for a long time with limited success. (There are a lot of instructions and tutorials out there but a lot of it is outdated and no longer relevant or works.) What I am trying to do is create a GAS that delivers data as an object from a google sheet to a javascript request. I have several limitations - the JS resides on an internal only intranet, my Chrome (v58.0) settings restricts XMLHttpRequest (which works perfectly in my version of IE10), I cannot access the developer console in Chrome (I can in IE) and I cannot use JQuery or any other plugin. Everything on the GAS side seems to work and delivers what it should, but the JS seems to be the problem.

When I access the page direct (via what is produced by doGet(), the text result of the object is delivered. All data shows up like it should but as plain text.

Here's my GAS (execute as me, anonymous):

```
function doGet() {
var oReturnLinks = [];
var sLinks = SpreadsheetApp.openById("secret").getSheetByName("links");
var oLinks = sLinks.getSheetValues(2, 1, -1, -1);

//loop over data and determine what to return
for (a=0;a<oLinks.length;a++) {
    if (oLinks[a][0] == true && oLinks[a][1].trim() != '' && oLinks[a][2].trim() != '' && oLinks[a][3].trim() != '' && oLinks[a][4].trim() != '' ) {

        oReturnLinks.push(oLinks[a]);

    }

}

if (oReturnLinks.length > 0) {

    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(oReturnLinks)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);

} else {

    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify("no data returned")).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);

}
```

}

Then in my JS on my intranet (this works in IE10):

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "https://script.google.com/macros/s/secret/exec", false);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhttp.send();
var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
```

I've also tried this:

```
var s
s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/secret/exec";
var oResult = JSON.stringify(s);
alert(oResult);
```

...but it produces

> > {}

as the result.

If I add this to the output content:

```
'(' + JSON.stringify(oReturnLinks) + ')'
```

I get this:

> > [Object HTMLScriptElement]

...as the output.

If I change the mimetype in GAS to JSON, I get a SEC7112 error in IE (was blocked due to mime type mismatch) and some error in Chrome that I can't see.

There has to be a cross browser solution to this? I feel like it's something simple I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the MIME type as JAVASCRIPT instead of JSON.

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(oReturnLinks))
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```

Comment: Yes, i tried that and added the padding "(" on both ends of the output. That's when I get the SEC7112 error in IE